# For a function $f(x) = x^2-(n-a)x+a$, where $a$ and $n$ are integers $1 \le a < n \le 49$. No of values of $n$ such thats $f(x)$ has irrational roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a function $f(x) = x^2-(n-a)x+a$, where $a$ and $n$ are integers $1 \le a < n \le 49$. For how many values of $n$ does $f(x)$ have irrational roots for all possible values of $a$?

I first found that if $r$ and $s$ are the roots, then they must be integers as $f(x)$ is monic. Then, I found that $r+s = a-n$, and $rs=n$, so $rs-r-s+1=(r-1)(s-1)=n+1$. I don't know what to do next from here on. Any suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 1):

Hint: there are errors in your derivation.

$$rs=a, r+s=n-a \implies (r+1)(s+1) = n+1 $$

So $n+1$ must be a composite number.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If it has rational roots $r_1,r_2$ it will factor as $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ and so $r_1+r_2 = n-a$ and $r_1r_2 = a$.

In other words $r_1+r_2+r_1r_2=n$.  At this point we can do brute force on what $r_1, r_2$ can be.  (You noted they must both be integers.

Wolog $r_1 \le r_2$ so if $r_1 = 1$ we can have: $n = 1+r_2 + 1*r_2 = 1+2r_2$. That can be any odd number.  If $r_1 = 2$ we can have $n=2+r_2=2*r_2 = 2+3r_2$ i.e $n = 8,11,14,....,47$. If $r_1=3$ we can have $n=3+4r_2$ and so on up to $n = 6+7*r_2=48$.

We can use exclusion/inclusion to count the number of terms omitted.