Find no. of natural $n$ < 50 such that $x^2+(n-a)x+a$ has rational roots, for all natural values of '$a$' less than 50
Consider, $f(x)$=$x^2+(n-a)x+a$, where $a$,$n$ are natural numbers less than 50, such that $n$ is always greater than or equal to $a$. For how many values of n does $f(x)$ has rational roots for all values of $a$?
My method- we can find the discriminant and equate to $m^2$, but it is very difficult to solve a equation in 3 variables.  I don't see any other approach to this question other than this (probably there must be something special about $(n-a)$ and $a$ as coefficients)
Can anyone help me with a idea or hint involving only algebra?
(Source of problem- Art of Problem solving- Algebra)

"$f(x)$ has rational roots for all values of $x$?" Should the last $x$ be an $a$?

when $n=a, f(x)$ has no rational roots.

@ww1 in that case it doesn't have any real roots at all, as $a>0$. OP needs to provide more data

1/ Can you state the equation in 3 variables?  $\quad$ 2/ What conclusions can you draw from it?

You have several questions above which need response.  Also can't really agree it is always very difficult to find integer solutions to equations like $m^2-8a^2=n^2$, it would depend on what tools you're familiar with. Arguably, it is similar to finding Pythagorean triples - so where did you get this question and can you answer the above questions before people can provide appropriate help?

Here's a similar question (not the exact same equation, but maybe you could borrow the method): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954542/for-a-function-fx-x2-n-axa-where-a-and-n-are-integers-1-le-a

Since the discrimimant of $(n-a)^2-4a=m^2$ for $a$ must be perfect square, we get:
$$m^2+4n+4=v^2$$
$$a=n+2-v$$
Hence, $n=\dfrac{v^2-m^2-4}{4}$ where $(m,v)$ have same parity and $m<v<n+2.$
$\bullet$ Case $(v,m)=(2p,2q):$
$ (n,a)=(p^2-q^2-1,\ p^2-q^2-2p+1).$
$\bullet$ Case $(v,m)=(2p+1,2q+1):$
$ (n,a)=(p^2+p-q^2-q-1,\ p^2-p-q^2-q).$
 Search results for integral n.
 
             (n, a)  
            
           ( 3,  1 )
           ( 5,  2 )
           ( 7,  3 )
           ( 8,  4 )
           ( 9,  4 )
           (11,  5 )
           (11,  6 )
           (13,  6 )
           (14,  8 )
           (15,  7 )
           (15,  9 )
           (17,  8 )
           (17, 10 )
           (19,  9 )
           (19, 12 )
           (20, 12 )
           (21, 10 )
           (23, 11 )
           (23, 14 )
           (23, 15 )
           (24, 16 )
           (25, 12 )
           (26, 16 )
           (27, 13 )
           (27, 18 )
           (29, 14 )
           (29, 18 )
           (29, 20 )
           (31, 15 )
           (31, 21 )
           (32, 20 )
           (33, 16 )
           (34, 24 )
           (35, 17 )
           (35, 22 )
           (35, 24 )
           (35, 25 )
           (37, 18 )
           (38, 24 )
           (39, 19 )
           (39, 27 )
           (39, 28 )
           (41, 20 )
           (41, 26 )
           (41, 30 )
           (43, 21 )
           (43, 30 )
           (44, 28 )
           (44, 32 )
           (45, 22 )
           (47, 23 )
           (47, 30 )
           (47, 33 )
           (47, 35 )
           (48, 36 )
           (49, 24 )
           (49, 36 )


I could not solve this problem using a method without brute force which i helped with some remarks and cuts paths in numeric calculations. First, the only natural square discriminant ensures that the roots are integer or rational so it is enough to solve the diophantine (as many people, we discard $0$ from natural) $$(n-a)^2-4a=m^2;\space 1\le a\le n\le49$$
For  $x^2+(n-a)x+a$ the discriminant is $(n-a)^2-4a\ge0$. It follows:
For $n=49$ we must have $1\le a\le36$. For $n=48$ we must have $1\le a\le36$.
For $n=47$ we must have $1\le a\le35$
in short,
$$n=46\implies a\le34\\n=45\implies a\le33\\n=44\implies a\le32\\n=43\implies a\le31\\n=41,42\implies a\le30\\n=40\implies a\le29\\n=39\implies a\le28\\n=38\implies a\le27\\n=37\implies a\le26\\n=36\implies a\le25\\n=35\implies a\le25\\n=34\implies a\le24\\n=33\implies a\le23\\n=32\implies a\le22\\n=31\implies a\le21\\n=29,30\implies a\le20\\n=28\implies a\le19\\n=27\implies a\le18\\n=26\implies a\le17$$ $$ n=25\implies a\le16\\ n=24\implies a\le16\\n=23\implies a\le15\\n=22\implies a\le14\\n=21\implies a\le13\\n=19,20\implies a\le12\\n=18\implies a\le11\\n=17\implies a\le10\\n=15,16\implies a\le9\\n=14\implies a\le8\\n=13\implies a\le7\\n=11,12\implies a\le6\\n=10\implies a\le5\\n=8,9\implies a\le4\\n=7\implies a\le3\\n=5,6\implies a\le2\\n=3,4\implies a\le1$$
With this and helped by the function $f(x)=\sqrt{(n-x)^2-4x}$  we find
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
n & a & x^2+(n-a)x+a\\ \hline
49&24,36 &x^2+25x+24;\space x^2+13x+36\\\hline
48&36&x^2+12x+36  \\ \hline
47&23,30,33,35&x^2+24x+23;\space x^2+17x+30;\space x^2+14x+33;\space x^2+12x+35\\ \hline
46& \text{none}&\\ \hline
45&22&x^2+23x+22\\\hline44&28,32&x^2+16x+28;\space x^2+12x+32\\ \hline43&21,30&x^2+22x+21;\space x^2+13x+30\\\hline42&\text{none}\\\hline41&20,26,30&x^2+21x+20;\space x^2+15x+26;\space x^2+11x+30\\\hline40&\text{none}\\\hline39&19,27,28&x^2+20x+19;\space x^2+12x+27;\space x^2+11x+28\\\hline38&24&x^2+14x+24\\\hline37&18&x^2+19x+18\\\hline36&\text{none}\\\hline35&17,22,24&x^2+18x+17;\space x^2+13x+22;\space x^2+11x+24\\\hline34&24&x^2+10x+24\\\hline33&16&x^2+17x+16\\\hline32&20&x^2+12x+20\\\hline31&15,21&x^2+16x+15;\space x^2+10x+21\\\hline30&\text{none}\\\hline29&14,18,20&x^2+15x+14;\space x^2+14x+18;\space x^2+9x+20\\\hline28&\text{none}\\\hline27&13,18&x^2+14x+13;\space x^2+9x+18\\\hline26&16&x^2+10x+16\\\hline25&12&x^2+13x+12\\\hline24&\text{none}\\\hline23&11,14,15&x^2+12x+11;\space x^2+9x+14;\space x^2+8x+15\\\hline22&\text{none}\\\hline21&10&x^2+11x+10\\\hline20&12&x^2+8x+12\\\hline19&9,12&x^2+10x+9;\space x^2+7x+12\\\hline18&\text{none}\\\hline17&8,10&x^2+9x+8;\space x^2+7x+10\\\hline16&\text{none}\\\hline15&7&x^2+8x+7\\\hline14&8&x^2+6x+8\\\hline13&6&x^2+7x+6\\\hline12&\text{none}\\\hline11&5,6&x^2+6x+5;\space x^2+5x+6\\\hline10&\text{none}\\\hline9&4&x^2+5x+4\\\hline8&4&x^2+4x+4\\\hline7&3&x^2+4x+3\\\hline6&\text{none}\\\hline5&2&x^2+3x+2\\\hline4&\text{none}\\\hline3&1&x^2+2n+1\\\hline2&\text{none}\\\hline1&\text{none}\\\hline\end{array}$$
This gives $54$ as the required number of solutions.

How does your answer exceed 49?

I can make you sure, I didn't downvote

@PrinceChoudhary.- The number of solutions is greater than 49 because for some numbers, for example $47$, there are four solutions  (i.e. more then one solution). The number of solutions is equal to the total of  number of values of  $a$ in the table. I am completely persuaded that some put me downvotes for simple bad intention against me because otherwise it is not explained that they put downvotes for something not only correct but also laborious and that it has demanded a lot of will.

Yeah ok, by the way I asked no. Of n which by your solution is 33, but the actual answer is 34
